# how to order by a column with concatenated first and last name

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, concatenation

I'm having trouble using the order by command. Since last and first name are concatenated into fullname, I can't order by LastName since sql developer doesn't recognize LastName after it's been concatenated. I'm trying to do order by DoubleDip(Major1), LastName, FirstName. It only orders by DoubleDip. How should I fix this issue?

```
 Create View A5T5 As 
 Select FirstName || ' ' || LastName As Fullname, StudentID, Upper(Major1) As DoubleDip  
 From A5
 Where Upper(Major1)= Upper(Major2) 
 Order by DoubleDip, LastName, FirstName
```

Comment: Have you tried `ORDER BY FullName`?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do:

```
ORDER BY FirstName || ' ' || LastName
```

Comment: I am not trying to sort by FullName, but by "LastName" and then "FirstName". Due to the select statement of "FirstName || ' ' || LastName As Fullname", the query seems to not be accepting LastName as an OrderBy parameter. It will only recognize "FullName" b/c that is the defined selected value. 

The issue is that I have selected FullName, and am now trying to sort by LastName. LastName has not been selected but rather concatenated into FullName. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using mySql? Sql server? Oracle? You should still be able to sort by lastname even if you concatenate

Comment: ahh ok, not too familiar with Oracle so I can't help you there, but in MySQL, MSSQL etc, you can still order by lastname, firstname even when it's not part of your select